# What is the most efficient way to modify a string in php?

Tags: php, string, string-formatting

I need to change a string from a format such as
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` to `ab/cd/ef/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

What is the most efficient way to do this in php?

Examples:

`123456789` would become `12/34/56/123456789`

`gwn58yh045bgw0r8` would become `gw/n5/8y/gwn58yh045bgw0r8`

Comment: Not sure what all the downvotes are about.

Comment: Probably because your question was originally unclear. I've removed my downvote because you have since clarified your question.

Comment: I see now.  Thanks.  Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, much better. Thank you. (Unfortunately, several people may not return to see that you've improved your question. :-/ )

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit, Wiseguy.  I'll remember to highlight in future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `preg_replace`.  This code should do it:

```
$input = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$output = preg_replace('/^(..)(..)(..).*$/', "$1/$2/$3/$input", $input);
```

This take the first 3 groups of two characters `(..)` and prepends them (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`) to the original string, with slashes.

Demo: http://codepad.org/WueutXZA

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

*Note:* Since Jeff B beat me to the `preg_replace` solution, his is the most efficient.  But just to provide another (completely unreadable) alternative...

```
$inStr = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

$temp = substr($inStr,0, 6);
$outStr = substr_replace(
            substr_replace(
                substr_replace($temp, '/', 2, 0)
            , '/', 5, 0)
          , '/', 8, 0);

echo($outStr . $inStr);
```